# How can I prove this statement regarding a discrete-time algebraic Riccati inequality?

Tags: matrix-equations, control-theory, optimal-control, lyapunov-functions

Consider the square matrix $X \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$. In a [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1333199) that I'm currently reading, the authors state that, if the following two conditions are met:
$$
\begin{align}
&(1) \quad AXA^T - X + Q - AXC^T(CXC^T + R)^{-1}CXA^T \preceq 0 \\
&(2) \quad \textrm{$(A,Q^{1/2})$ is controllable}
\end{align}
$$
where

- $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n},C \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}, Q \succeq 0,R \succ 0$, and
- $(A,Q^{1/2})$ being controllable means that there exists a $P_1 \succ 0$ such that $A^TP_1A - P_1 \prec 0$, or equivalently that there exists a $P_2 \succ 0$ such that $AP_2A^T - P_2 + Q = 0$,

then $X \succ 0$. I'm not entirely sure how to check whether this statement is true or false, so I would appreciate any hints.

---

For reference, the statement given in the paper is actually more general than the one I mentioned above. That is, let $\lambda \in [0,1]$ and define the function
$$
g_\lambda(X) = AXA^T + Q - \lambda AXC^T(CXC^T + R)^{-1}CXA^T
$$
Then, in lemma 1(g) in Appendix A in the paper (page 1460, right column), the authors state that, for every $\lambda \in [0,1]$, if $(A,Q^{1/2})$ is controllable and $X \succeq g_\lambda(X)$, then $X \succ 0$.

To prove this, the authors first show that, for every $\lambda \in [0,1]$, $g_\lambda(X) \succeq (1-\lambda)AXA^T + Q$ (this is lemma 1(f)). The proof of this is straightforward. Finally, the authors give the following proof for lemma 1(g) (emphasis on the word "detectable" is mine):

> From fact f), it follows that $X \succeq g_\lambda(X) \succeq (1-\lambda)AXA^T + Q$. Let $\hat X$ such that $\hat X = (1-\lambda)A\hat X A^T + Q$. Such $\hat X$ must clearly exist. Therefore, $X - \hat X \succeq (1-\lambda)A(X - \hat X)A^T \succeq 0$. Moreover, the matrix $\hat X$ solves the Lyapunov equation $\hat X = \tilde A\hat X \tilde A^T + Q$ where $\tilde A = \sqrt{1-\lambda} A$. Since $(\tilde A,Q^{1/2})$ is **detectable**, it follows that $\hat X \succ 0$ and so $X \succ 0$, which proves the fact.

I'm not sure if it is possible to use this proof for my case (when $\lambda = 1$). Also, I think the authors made a mistake when they wrote "Since $(\tilde A,Q^{1/2})$ is *detectable*..." and I think it should instead be "Since $(\tilde A,Q^{1/2})$ is *controllable*...", since they never assumed that $(A,Q^{1/2})$ is detectable anywhere in the paper, only controllable.

Comment: Does the paper provide a proof? Or a reference to a proof?

Comment: Or is your question how, in a concrete situation, you can check that the conditions are true?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth thank you for the comments. I've added the proof given in the paper, although it is for a more general statement than mine. I'm essentially trying to prove a special case of their statement, but I'm just not able to tailor their proof for my special case. I also think that there may be a typo in their proof.

Comment: This is a standard result on Riccati equations. You can find the proof in books on the topic such as "Matrix Riccati Equations in Control and Systems Theory" by Abou-Kandil et al.

Comment: @KBS thanks for the comment. Could you please be more specific about where in this book the result is? I’ve already checked several books for this result, including Boyd’s “LMI’s in Systems and Control” book, after someone else told me the same thing, and I couldn’t find it, so I would prefer to have a concrete answer this time.

Comment: In the chapter on the discrete algebraic Riccati equation.

Comment: @KBS Thanks. I think theorem 2.3.4 under section 2.3, specifically equation (2.47), in the first edition of Abou-Kandil's 2003 book helped the most here. The result is not specifically stated, but I think I can manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer in section 13.1 in the book

> P. Lancaster and L. Rodman, Algebraic Riccati equations. in Oxford science publications. Oxford : New York: Clarendon Press ; Oxford University Press, 1995.

More specifically, using theorem 13.1.1, corollary 13.1.2, and theorem 13.1.3 in section 13.1 in this book, we can show that, if $(A,Q)$ is controllable and $(C,A)$ is detectable, and if there exists a matrix $X \succeq 0$ such that
$$
X \preceq AXA^T + Q - AXC^T(CXC^T + R)^{-1}CXA^T
$$
then $X \succ 0$.